# Centering flexbox wrap on mobile viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

How can I center the stacked item on mobile viewport?

Here is my snippet:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.space-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.space-between div {
  background: pink;
}

.flex-item {
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container space-between ">
  <div class="flex-item">very long text 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">very long text 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">very long text 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're willing to use `space-around` instead of `space-between`, the items will center naturally (no media query necessary). https://jsfiddle.net/upnv69Lt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@media-query` for the mobile view. After refactoring your HTML and CSS, here is your updated code

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between; 

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex-container {
    justify-content: center; 
 }
}

.flex-container div {
  background: pink;
}

.flex-item {
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container space-between ">
  <div class="flex-item">very long text 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">very long text 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">very long text 3</div>
</div>
```